# Limiting no of outputs in Hibernate query

Tags: hibernate, grails, groovy, frameworks, grails-orm

I have a hibernate query in grails

```
 Book.findAllByRating(4)
```

In the above query i want only 5 number of outputs.How do I limit the output to 5?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [GORM documentation](http://grails.org/DomainClass+Dynamic+Methods) has some examples of this. Have you tried out:

```
Book.findAllByRating(4, [max:5])
```